# Bazel: how outputRoot and --disk_cache relate regarding local caching?

Tags: bazel

I see bazel places lots of assets under `~/.cache/bazel`. Given that this is already a cache, what is the usage for `--disk_cache` flag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`--disk_cache` makes sense when you have two directories which contain a `WORKSPACE` file and build almost the same stuff. Without `--disk_cache` both workspaces will have their own cached artifacts in `~/.cache/bazel` and with `--disk_cache` they can share their artifacts.

As piarston pointed out:

> You can use `--disk_cache` without setting up a remote cache. You can
>   even have `--disk_cache=~/.cache/bazel` if you want.

Comment: You can use `--disk_cache` without setting up a remote cache. You can even have `--disk_cache=~/.cache/bazel` if you want.

Comment: @pairston Thanks for clarifying this. I changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: `--disk_cache` is also useful if you want Bazel to remember all of the previous builds instead of just the most recent one, which is helpful when changing branches.

Comment: This is indeed a very important difference - running `bazel build` without `--disk_cache` will result in re-builds if you make changes and change them back, even inside the same directory.